# How to case where condition SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a batch update of my data with date filter.

```
   below is my sample table[myTable] data:
   +--------+------------+-----------+
   |   ID   |    Amount  |  ResetDay |  
   +--------+------------+-----------+
   |   1    |    100     |     1     |
   +--------+------------+-----------+
   |   2    |    100     |     2     |
   +--------+------------+-----------+
   |   3    |    100     |     29    |
   +--------+------------+-----------+
   |   4    |    100     |     30    |
   +--------+------------+-----------+
```

Here's my query:

```
   update myTable set Amount = 0
   where ID in (case when ResetDay > day(eomonth(getdate()))
   then (select ID from myTable where ResetDay > day(eomonth(getdate())))
   else (select ID from myTable where ResetDay = day(getdate()))) end)
```

I have a automatic batch update with date trigger. I'm using conditions that when the `ResetDay` is greater than the end of month day it will update all the data that has greater `ResetDay`. and if not it will only update the data that is equal to the date.

Sample Query & Expected output:
Query: (This is for sample of the month end day is less than ResetDay)

```
  update myTable set Amount = 0
  where ID in (case when ResetDay > 28
  then (select ID from myTable where ResetDay > 28)
  else (select ID from myTable where ResetDay = 1) end) 

  Output:
   +--------+------------+-----------+
   |   ID   |    Amount  |  ResetDay |  
   +--------+------------+-----------+
   |   1    |    100     |     1     |
   +--------+------------+-----------+
   |   2    |    100     |     2     |
   +--------+------------+-----------+
   |   3    |    0       |     29    |
   +--------+------------+-----------+
   |   4    |    0       |     30    |
   +--------+------------+-----------+
```

How to case where condition SQL Server? As I get error when I run those queries `Subquery returned more than 1 value, This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.`

Comment: Sample data in the form of a query will be helpful

Comment: Simplify the query and *don't* use `CASE` in the `WHERE` clause. The cases you posted are essentially joins/subqueries. The only part that changes is the *inner* `WHERE` condition which means `CASE` in the outer query just adds noise. Don't use `CASE` in the `INNER` query either though. You're updating the *same* table which probably means you don't need that subquery at all.

Comment: When you say "when the ResetDay is greater than", you are talking about a value outside of the table?  Perhaps this is a value provided by your batch process.  Is this correct?

Comment: I'm not following the logic of your where clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is essentially a self join. That's not needed at all though and seems to be a result of trying to use `CASE` when it's not needed.

The *same* query could be rewritten as :

```
update myTable 
set Amount = 0
where (ResetDay > day(eomonth(getdate())) and ResetDay > day(eomonth(getdate())))
     OR (ResetDay <= day(eomonth(getdate())) and ResetDay = day(getdate())))
```

I'm not even trying to count parentheses here, those formulas shouldn't be in the query. A cleaner way to write this would be  :

```
declare @eomday int=day(eomonth(getdate())), @today int =day(getdate());

update myTable 
set Amount = 0
where (ResetDay > @eomday and ResetDay > @eomday)
     OR (ResetDay <= @eomday and ResetDay = @today)
```

It's obvious that the conditions aren't correct. The first pair is a duplicate while the second is equivalent to just `ResetDay=@today`, since the current month's day will always be greater or equal to today.

The query can be rewritten as  :

```
update myTable 
set Amount = 0
where ResetDay > @eomday 
     OR ResetDay = @today
```

That query says the same thing your requirement says :

> when the ResetDay is greater than the end of month day it will update all the data that has greater ResetDay. and if not it will only update the data that is equal to the date.